# How to initiate model without get() on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I have this on my model `Scholar`

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Scholar extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'scholar_id';
    protected $fillable = ['ngo_id','scholar_lname','scholar_fname','scholar_image','scholar_nickname','scholar_cityAddress','scholar_permaAddress','scholar_birthday','scholar_placebirth','scholar_age','scholar_gender','scholar_email','scholar_contact'];

}
```

then this is on my Controller

```
$scholars = new Scholar; <------

if(Input::get('age_from'))
    $scholars->where('age', '=', Input::get('age_from'));

$scholars->get();

return $scholars;
```

I want to initiate this, but when I try the `$scholars = Scholar::all();` I cant use `->get()` anymore;

Anyway how to do this optional `where`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [newQuery](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_newQuery);

```
$scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery();

if(Input::get('age_from')) {
    $scholars->where('age', '=', Input::get('age_from'));
}

return $scholars->get();
```

Comment: it return me this `Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newQuery() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

Comment: By static method: $scholars = Scholar::query();

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get all scholars anyway you can get all rows in a collection with just one query:

```
$allScholars = Scholar::all();
```

And then you can get any data from the collection:

```
$scholars = $allScholars->where('age', '=', Input::get('age_from'));
```

Now you all scholars in `$allScholars` collections and scholars of specified age in `$scholars` one.

Comment: I want to use to chop by chop query... cause I still have other query

Comment: Could you explain what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Using `all()` selects all data then `where()` filters the collection which is inefficient. You're loading all of the data in the table into memory then filtering through the results.

Comment: @BenSwinburne, OP wants to use `all()` anyway. Please read original question.

Comment: I suspect OP wants to use `get()` with a where clause but `all()` doesn't return a `Builder` object so you can't say `Scholar::all()->where()->get();` as that's not how it's supposed to be done. Either way, my comment about inefficiency stands as advice to OP.

Comment: @BenSwinburne, `all()` returns collection as I said in my answer. So you can use `where()` and you don't need to use `get()` method.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm saying loading all of the data then filtering it is not as efficient as filtering the data and loading what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not the best way to do it but it works

Try something like:

```
$scholars = Scholar::where('id','>',0); //Assuming you have an autoincrement id in your table

if(Input::get('age_from'))
    $scholars->where('age', '=', Input::get('age_from'));

$scholars->get();

return $scholars;
```